# Change branch that is switched to after deploying

Tags: git, capistrano

I have Capistrano deploying my `dev` branch to a staging environment

```
# capistrano/config/deploy.rb
set :branch, fetch(:branch, "dev")
```

However, once the deploy is complete, it's switching the code base to a branch called `deploy`

```
$ git branch
* deploy
  dev
```

How can I configure Capistrano to switch to a different branch, `staging` for instance? Or is there a way to get it to stay on the `dev` branch?

I wasn't able to find any information in Capistrano's readme or in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

I never used before but i found this for you.
Give it a try and update me if it worked or not. if not iwill read more about the configuration to figure out was in not set up correctly.

```
#call with cap -s env="<env>" branch="<branchname>" deploy
set :branch, fetch(:branch, "master")
set :env, fetch(:env, "production")
```